# Angular2 unable to fetch json from rest api

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

```
I tried to follow tutorial on angular.io (Tour the Heroes) Unlike in tutorial i tried to make GET request on locally deployed springboot application for which i couldnt get the hero's list on my angular app. (Same works with URL using in-memory-dataservice)
```

**JSON response from my API:**

```
[{"id":11,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":12,"name":"Narco"}]
```

**My code looks like below ( only change to tutorial is URL):**

```
private heroesUrlmain = 'http://localhost:8080/heros.json';  // URL to web api

private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrlmain)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

To service I import just few basic things:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Could you please advice change i need to correct so that angular app can get data from API using get method.

Adding @component:

**@Component code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  templateUrl: 'heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'heroes.component.css' ]
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }    
}
```

**Template :**

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)"
      [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span>
    <span>{{hero.name}}</span>
    <button class="delete"
            (click)="delete(hero); $event.stopPropagation()">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>
    {{selectedHero.name | uppercase}} is my hero
  </h2>
  <button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
  <label>Hero name:</label> <input #heroName />
  <button (click)="add(heroName.value); heroName.value=''">
    Add
  </button>
</div>
```

**handleError code asked as per the comment.**

```
private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Sefa Ümit Oray : There was no error message , but in my angular app isn't displaying heros  in webpage

Comment: That depends on your component and template code. Please edit your question and component and template code.

Comment: @Sefa Ümit Oray : I have added component code to my question.

Comment: @RakeshMothukuri but you still haven't posted your template. Also, have you checked the Network panel of your dev tools to verify that the JSON you receive is ineed the JSON posted in the question? What does `this.handleError()` do?

Comment: @JBNizet i have added template to the question now. In the network panel i dont see JSON data, but in console window i see error as below for the template "Response {_body: Object, status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers…}" I have added this.handleError method code to the question now.

Comment: So you have a server error. Read the error logs and fix it. It has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: I have tried with headers and without in angular, but issue remained same. What i don't understand is if issue is related to server error how service is responding when call is made via restclients(Advance Rest Client) ?

Comment: I wouldn't speculate on why the error occurs. Instead, I would read the exception stack trace to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array. An array doesn't have any field named `data`. And yet you're doing `response => response.json().data as Hero[]`.

You just need `response => response.json() as Hero[]`

Comment: I have tried removing .data from "response.json().data" in the code and did npm start, but the issue remains same.